# twitter bootstrap dropdown menu in wordpress appears behind revslider

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, slider

This is a small enough problem, but i can't seem to find where to adjust the z-index so that my dropdown menu appears on top of the slider layers. Currently the drop down is visible but not clickable. any help is much appreciated. It's a wordpress site and here is the url: http://goo.gl/Ch5pju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add z-index:2 to your rev_slider_1_1_wrapper element like following. The other ones shoul be inherited.

```
#rev_slider_1_1_wrapper
{
z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i was trying to adjust the dropdowns' z-index without any success! you saved the day!